# fglrx-legacy-driver not seeing Radeon HD 4650 AGP

Tags: debian, amd-radeon, fglrx, agp

I am running Debian Squeeze on an old Dell Dimension 8300 box.  It has an AGP Radeon HD 4650 card.  I use this machine to mine bitcoins, and today I noticed that the machine had rebooted!  My precious uptime!

Anyway, my miner wouldn't start, so I figured might as well update my graphics driver, maybe that would fix the issue.  I went to [amd.com](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx) and downloaded the newest driver (12.6 *legacy*), but after installing it, `aticonfig` gave an error:

> aticonfig: No supported adapters detected

I uninstalled the driver and figured I'd try to install it from apt.  AMD has dropped support for the HD 4000 series in fglrx, forcing me to use [fglrx-legacy-driver](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/fglrx-legacy-driver) (currently only in *experimental*).  In order to install this, I had to update libc6 (and some other important packages, like gcc), I had to use their wheezy versions.  I finally got fglrx-legacy-driver installed, but I still got:

> aticonfig: No supported adapters detected

Why isn't the driver finding my video card?  I have a hunch it has something to do with the fact that it's an AGP video card.

Here is the output of `lspci -v` (why does it say `Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci`?):

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV730 Pro AGP [Radeon HD 4600 Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 0028
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at de00 [size=256]
    Memory at fe9f0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at fea00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] AGP version 3.0
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

**EDIT**: fglrx 12.4 seems to work.  Thing is, since I am on kernel 3.2, I need to apply [this patch](http://pastebin.com/xLTdXwtb) to `common/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/firegl_public.c`.  I thought ATI dropped support for the 4xxx series *after* 12.4.  Why doesn't 12.6 legacy work?

Comment: Is it possible that I overheated/killed the card?  How can I test this?

Comment: I realized that kernel 3.2 *might* not support fglrx.  I'm running `3.2.0-0.bpo.3-686-pae`.

Comment: fglrx 12.4 works just fine.  Only thing is, I need to apply [this patch](http://pastebin.com/xLTdXwtb) to `common/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/firegl_public.c` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimental drivers are called "experimental" because they are unstable and not efficiently tested. As a result, weird problems, errors and glitches can result. With this in mind, I suggest you try an earlier stable version (i.e. the latest stable release, rather than the latest release in general)

Good luck, hope this works! If not, leave a comment and I'll look further into it.

Comment: I got 12.4 to work correctly.  That was the last one (before legacy) that supported my card.

Comment: are you able to apply the patch on 12.4? or is that why you need 12.6 to work?

Comment: In order to get 12.4 to install, I need the patch.  I only wanted 12.6 because 6 is bigger than 4 :-P

Comment: oh ok, so problems solved then?

Comment: I guess.  12.4 seems to work.  It'd be nice to figure out how to get 12.6-legacy working, though.